# SQL View: Optimizing real-time data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue with a query a while to run.

The scenario is this: I have an efficiency metric being populated within a view taking in inputs from another view. This calculation utilizes `GETUTCDATE()`and I am just adjusting for my time zone. I am calculating efficiency by way of using a "BuildTime" column value versus how much time has passed since 7:00 AM of the current day (e.g. if 120min have passed since 7AM and "BuildTime" equals 120min, the efficiency is 100%. I am also using a `CASE` function to only calculate the current passing time between operating hours (7AM - 3:30PM)

Attached below is the code:

```
SELECT
    md.Operator,

    CASE 
    WHEN DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()) > CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()))) + '7:00' AND GETDATE() < CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()))) + '15:30' THEN
    (SUM(isNull(md.TotalTime, 0)) + SUM(isNull(md.DelTime, 0))) * 1.0 / DATEDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()))) + '7:00' , DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE())) * 100.0
    ELSE (SUM(isNull(md.TotalTime, 0)) + SUM(isNull(md.DelTime, 0))) / 435 * 100.0
    END
    AS OpEfficiency


FROM [Booms MES Master Data] as md
WHERE md.[Date] = CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()), 101)
GROUP BY md.Operator
```

As of now, this code takes several seconds to run. I'm wondering where the problem lays within the code? Am I converting too many statements or is it an issue with a nested if function?

Comment: You would need to look at the execution plan, but the issue is probably the `group by`.  How many rows are being processed?

Comment: Not many at all.. at the moment, less than a hundred. I'm worried that the dataset will take much longer when the data scales.

Comment: When you say less than a hundred, do you mean you get less than a hundred rows back or that there are less than a hundred in `[Booms MES Master Data]`? What is the size of the table itself if not and is there an index on `[Date]`?

Comment: Does "populated within a view taking in inputs from another view" mean that you have a view that is pulling data from another view? Nested views are horrific from a performance perspective. Grant Fritchey has a great discussion on the topic here. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/the-seven-sins-against-tsql-performance/#seven

Comment: Also, why are you converting a date value to a string to compare against md.[Date]? Are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: Thanks for the great answers all. I am storing the dates as strings as I am connecting this server to Microsoft PowerApps which does not work well with actual DATETIME values from SQL. I will check out the "nested function" articles as well as limiting conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a very large dataset, as a rule of thumb, start with your fixed value first and limit your conversion to the minimal amount of characters. In this case varchar(10) since a 101 format date only has 10 character ( '12/12/1234' ).

```
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE()), 101) = md.[Date]
```

You can use Microsoft's Analyze an Actual Execution Plan to detect the further issues.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/analyze-an-actual-execution-plan

Also consider converting to dates instead of varchar, if you code is running on sql server 2012+. Dates are stored as two integer in sql server. It is far easier for sql to find a specific number once sorted than searching for a string sorted as mm/dd/yy if you have multiple years of data.

```
WHERE CONVERT(date, DATEADD(HOUR, -6, GETUTCDATE())) = CONVERT(date,md.[Date])
```